# What is the difference between tar zxvf and tar -zxvf?

Tags: linux, zip

Today I tried to unzip one file in Linux, I used 2 kinds of orders

```
1.tar zxvf zookeeper-3.4.6.tar.gz
2.tar -zxvf zookeeper-3.4.6.tar.gz
```

It seems both of the 2 orders are same, do they have some differences between them?

Comment: The default command is `tar xvf zookeeper-3.4.6.tar.gz` .... since year 2004 ... Quote : "tar version 1.15 - Sergey Poznyakoff, 2004-12-20
 Compressed archives are recognised automatically, it is no longer
necessary to specify -Z, -z, or -j options to read them. 
( Thus, you can now run `tar tf archive.tar.gz'.)
So now you can just do : 'tar xvf [archive]' with tar.gz and tar.bz2 . And : Year 2009? lzma was added to be recognised automatically : files.tar.xz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash is optional, and doesn't change the meaning of the command. Here's an excerpt from the GNU tar man page:

> The first argument to tar should be a function; either one of the letters
>        `Acdrtux`, or one of the long function names.  A function letter need not
>        be prefixed with `-`,  and may be combined with other single-letter
>        options.

In your case, you have combined the function letter `x` with the single-letter options `z`, `v` and `f`.